# Getting a UK visitor visa for my girlfriend

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

As the title states, I'm looking to get a visitor visa for my girlfriend for our trip in August. I know it's late, but the trip wasn't planned very well. Regardless, I'm planning on paying for the priority application so it shouldn't be an issue.

I'm a Canadian citizen with a valid Canadian passport. She's a Permanent Resident of Canada, but she's from the Philippines with a Philippines passport.

The trip is from the 7th of August to the 17th. We plan on visiting some of my family, as well as doing some tourist activities.

I've seen that a lot of the time, people are denied on the basis of finances. Her finances aren't great at the moment. She used to have one bank account, but recently opened an account with a different bank and began using that one. Basically using the other as her savings account. Recently she had to empty her savings in order to help her mother pay for their house. So, around $25,000 CAD was withdrawn to help pay.

I also transferred her $2,500 CAD to help pay, which will be shown on both her and my statements.

I'm paying for the entire trip, flight, hotel, everything. With the flight and hotel paid for, I have around $10,000 in my bank account left over to cover any costs of the trip.

I know I see it asked a lot, but what are her chances of getting a visitor visa? And what documents should I provide to help better my case?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be nothing you can do other than make a good application and see how it goes. We can't really provide any quantitative estimates of "chances of getting a visa".

It is good that you document your economy in addition to hers. Large unexplained transfers into applicants' accounts tend to make ECOs curious, but that should be easily dealt with by being upfront about it and explaining it in the application.

Keep in mind that finances are not in themselves at criterion for visas ("you must be *this* rich to go on the UK ride"), but are used in the visa process as a proxy for how attractive it would be for the applicant to abscond and stay illegally in the UK. If the application has evidence that speaks more directly to that risk, finances will be comparatively less important. So once you've explained whatever possible strangenesses there are in the bank statements concentrate your effort on showing how established a life she has in Canada.

Having permanent residence in Canada is a huge plus to begin with, compared to applying from a less affluent country.

If she has a stable job, that will be good.

If *you* have a stable job and the two of you have a joint household, that's also good.

If you're not living together in Canada (it sounds like she shares a house with her mother?) look for other ways to document the stability of your relationship, Put yourself in the mind of a skeptical ECO ("what if the guy is just paid by the girl's family to pretend to sponsor her, so she can get into the promised land?") and try to think of documentable facts that would be inconsistent with such hypotheses.

Comment: She has a stable job, not a great one, she works at McDonalds. Around $2,000 CAD a month. But at the time of the application, she will only have around $1,200 in the bank to show on a statement. Like I said, the rest was withdrawn to help pay for a house for her mom. We can get a letter of employment.

Comment: @pfoamvisa: Stable is what counts. She wouldn't earn the equivalent of CA$2000 as an undocumented immigrant in the UK, and she's likely to know that. That's what the ECO cares about.

Comment: Is 1 year and 9 months earning the same income considered stable?

Comment: At this point I'll refer you to the first paragraph of my answer. Would a concrete yes or no response from a random stranger on the internet make you act any different? No it wouldn't, and it shouldn't.

Comment: @pfoamvisa Sounds pretty stable to me. I would say she has a good chance.